# What is a "template" in Perl?

Tags: perl, templates

I can find all sorts of weird information about templates in Perl, but nothing about what they actually are.

Are they generic types like in C++?  Is it a class-like structure?  Or maybe something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't link to any of the 'weird information' you found, but there is no language construct in Perl called 'templates'.

Generally, I expect the subject of any article on Perl and templating to be about text output; a template to generate HTML, or an email, for example. The [`Text::Template`](http://search.cpan.org/~mjd/Text-Template-1.45/lib/Text/Template.pm) and [`HTML::Template`](http://search.cpan.org/~wonko/HTML-Template-2.91/lib/HTML/Template.pm) modules being canonical examples.

Comment: http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tutorial/Web.html ; for example.  Also, could it have something to do with regex?

Comment: @Michael: The tutorial you link to is doing exactly what I described; using a template to produce HTML output. Text templating *could* be done using regular expressions, but that's not necessary (nor necessarily a good idea).

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Now that I look at it further, the examples given in the link I provided are pretty straightforward.  Initially, I googled it and all the sites that came up were awkward (like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790253/do-you-have-a-good-perl-template-script).

Comment: @Michael: Right; that's someone asking for a template to use when starting a new Perl source file. :-)